# Hibernate key-many-to-one

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have a problem getting the right data out of the table. The class `CompanyActualData` contains a member of the class `CompanyActualDataPK`. The class `CompanyActualDataPK` contains a member of the class `Entity` and the String `isin`. `Entity` has a String `visibility`, that I would like to filter for.
I would like to get all `CompanyActualData`, having a special `visibility` and a special `isin`.

At the moment I struggle creating the right criteria.

```
List<CompanyActualData> l = 
    session.createCriteria(CompanyActualData.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("companyActualDataPK.isin", isin))
    .createCriteria("companyActualDataPK")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("companyActualDataPK.entity.visible", visibility))
    .list();
```

I always get the error

> could not resolve property: companyActualDataPK.entity.visible of:
>   de.ll.web.pm.services.company.actual.CompanyActualData

Perhaps anybody has a hint.

```
<class name="de.ll.web.pm.services.company.actual.CompanyActualData" schema = "reporting"   table="company_actual">

        <composite-id name="companyActualDataPK" class="de.ll.web.pm.services.company.actual.CompanyActualDataPK">          
            <key-property name="isin" column="isin"/>
            <key-property name="countryId" column="country_id"/>
            <key-many-to-one  name="entity"     class="de.ll.web.pm.services.entity.Entity" lazy="false" >
                <column name="entity_id"></column> 
            </key-many-to-one> 
        </composite-id>

        <property name="sedol" column="sedol" not-null="false" />
        <property name="valueDouble" column="value_double" not-null="false" />
        <property name="valueString" column="value_string" not-null="false" />
        <property name="date" column="date_id" not-null="false" />

        <many-to-one name="currency"
            class="de.ll.web.pm.services.currency.Currency" lazy="false" insert="false" update="false">
            <column name="currency_id"></column>
        </many-to-one>  
    </class>
```

>

```
<class name="de.ll.web.pm.services.entity.Entity"
        table="md_entity" schema="reporting">

        <id name="entityId" column="entity_id" type="java.lang.String">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <property name="name" column="name" />
        <property name="description" column="description" />
        <property name="vendor" column="vendor" />
        <property name="visible" column="is_visible" type="java.lang.String"  />
        <property name="currency" column="is_currency" type="java.lang.String" />
</class>
```

Answer (score 1):

By doing `createCriteria("companyActualDataPK")`, the `Criteria` is getting rooted at the PK class. All property names given in following `Restriction`s will be relative to the `CompanyActualDataPK` class.

Try doing:

```
List<CompanyActualData> l = 
    session.createCriteria(CompanyActualData.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("companyActualDataPK.isin", isin))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("companyActualDataPK.entity.visible", visibility))
    .list();
```

Comment: Thanks Xavi, but I am getting   org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: companyActualDataPK.entity.visible of: de.ll.web.pm.services.company.actual.CompanyActualData   I can access the entity, but the problem seems to be the property visible.

Comment: Could you please post the relevant mapping/entity of `de.ll.web.pm.services.entity.Entity` in the question ?

Comment: I have added the mapping of entity. Everything works fine, when removing the Restriction of visible. The object is filled correct.

Comment: Don't get it to work right now. Everything is fine without adding a restriction for Entity. At the moment I have a workaround filtering the result manually and remove the rows having not the right visibility in a loop.  :-(